# public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int coun

Tags: java, android

### Changing all letters to "0" in edittext ontextchanged listener

I have used an edittext which is to get a number. If the user input
has more than 20 digits, then the first 15 digits will be same and remaining will be changed by "0". On every press,"THE LETTER SHOULD BE CHANGED AS 0".

Here is my code so far:

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, 
    int count) {

    amount1.removeTextChangedListener(tt3);
    if(s.length()>20)
    {
        String x=amount1.getText().toString();
        amount1.setText(x.substring(0, 15) + y1);//y1="00000"
        y1=y1+"0";
    }
    amount1.setSelection(amount1.getText().toString().length());
    amount1.addTextChangedListener(tt3);
}
```

The problem is that when I am pressing back button, it is adding `y1(String)` instead clearing the last digit.

Could you please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: `back` or `backspace` (delete) on the softkeyboard button?

Comment: yeah,backspace key.